# Which symbol in kallsyms file corresponds to system call entry point?

Tags: linux-kernel, trace

According to my understanding, whenever a system call is invoked, the execution goes through a certain address (also called system call entry point) which is written in kallsyms file. What is the name of this symbol in Linux kernel 4.2.0-34-generic?

I think in the previous kernel version, the name of this symbol was system_call (I might be wrong here).

I am basically trying to set a probe at this point in memory so whenever a system call is invoked, I can print out that a system call was invoked.

Comment: See the symbols like `SyS_{syscall_name}` and `sys_{syscall_name}`: SyS_read, sys_read, SyS_write, sys_write, etc. I am not 100% sure they are it but it looks like they are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is specific to a system call. I am trying to trap all of the system calls and I want to know if there is a symbol that is executed when any system call is invoked.